# Hiding results titles if there were no results

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have the following code that shows the output of a search for users, groups and posts :

```
<header><h1>Users results</h1></header>
@foreach ($users as $user)
@include('user.userblock')
@endforeach

<header><h1>Groups results</h1></header>
@foreach ($groups as $group)
@include('group.gruopblock')
@endforeach

<header><h1>Posts results</h1></header>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
@include('post.postblock')
@endforeach
```

How can I hide the `<header>` if one of them doesn't have results ?

Comment: I would use an if statement checking if $users etc were NOT null and paste your code after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (count($users))
    <header><h1>Users results</h1></header>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    @include('user.userblock')
    @endforeach
@endif
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Using eloquent `@if` and `@endif` with it s `count()` function:

```
@if(count($users))
<header><h1>Users results</h1></header>
@foreach ($users as $user)
@include('user.userblock')
@endforeach
@endif

@if(count($groups))
<header><h1>Groups results</h1></header>
@foreach ($groups as $group)
@include('group.gruopblock')
@endforeach
@endif

@if(count($posts))
<header><h1>Posts results</h1></header>
@foreach ($posts as $post)
@include('post.postblock')
@endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got several choices on how to do it thanks to the nature of the Laravel collection.  But an if check conditional on either side will work fine:

```
if (empty($users)) { // Your header and foreach}
if ($users->first()) { // Your header and foreach} 
if (!$users->isEmpty()) { // Your header and foreach}
if ($users->count()) { // Your header and foreach}
```